# jq: map field array with different length

Tags: arrays, json, jq, export-to-csv

I'm working with those JSONs:

```json
{
  "extension": [
    {
      "url": "url1",
      "system": "system1"
    },
    {
      "url": "url2",
      "system": "system2"
    }
  ]
}
{
  "extension": [
    {
      "url": "url3",
      "system": "system3"
    }
  ]
}
```

As you can see, both JSON objects have different `.extension` lenght.

I'm using this command in order to map input JSONs:

```
jq --raw-output '[.extension[] | .url, .system] | @csv'
```

You can find [jqplay here](https://jqplay.org/s/2XxTtXfRlX).

I'm getting that:

```
"url1","system1","url2","system2"
"url3","system3"
```

What I would like to get is:

```
"url1","system1","url2","system2"
"url3","system3",,
```

Any ideas about how I could map those "fields" "correctly"?

Comment: How does it work? Does `extension` always meant to have 2 pairs of key/values?

Comment: Yes, all `extension` items have an `url` and a `system` fields

Comment: But how many elements in the `extension` array. Is it indeterminate or always 2? The only way to get `"url3","system3",,` is by assuming there are two pairs of values, even though only one is defined

Comment: Yes, it's indeterminate

Comment: Then how do you expect to get `"url3","system3",,` which assumes there are 2 pairs of url/system ?

Comment: At most 4, at least can be empty as well. So, length can be 0, 1, 2, 3 or 4.

Comment: I'm not quite figure out what do you mean... I need to populate interterminated arrray of {url/system} objects to fixed lenght csv fields, at most 4. I don't know if I've explaoned so well.

Comment: Do you happen to know the length?

Comment: You can do some ugly padding like so: `[ [ .extension[] | .url, .system ] ][] | if length <= 2 then (. + [ "", "" ]) else . end | @csv` but I'm not sure how to make the `2` dynamic using the longest array

Comment: @0stone0 For the static length solution simply insert the desired length as `range`: `[.extension[range(2)] | .url, .system] | @csv`. In the case of just two pairs, direct enumeration is even simpler: `[.extension[0,1] | .url, .system] | @csv`. For a completely dynamic solution, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70183565/2158479) below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flip the table twice using `transpose | transpose` to fill up the slots missing from the unrigged square shape with `null`:

```sh
jq -rs 'map(.extension) | transpose | transpose[] | map(.url, .system) | @csv'
```

```
"url1","system1","url2","system2"
"url3","system3",,
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/-cryuF2X1b)

Answer (score 1):

A fairly efficient solution:

```
def pad:
  (map(length)|max) as $mx
  | map( . + [range(length;$mx)|null] );

[inputs | [.extension[] | (.url, .system)]]
| pad[]
| @csv
```

This of course should be used with the -n command-line option.