# jq: getting default when an item array doesn0t exist

Tags: jq

I'm getting an issue with those two json objects:

```
{
   "generalPractitioner":[
      {
         "extension":[
            {
               "url":"http://catsalut.gencat.cat/fhir/StructureDefinition/patient-tipus-relacio",
               "valueCodeableConcept":{
                  "coding":[
                     {
                        "system":"http://catsalut.gencat.cat/fhir/StructureDefinition/tipus-rel-organitzacio",
                        "code":"UPAPASSIG"
                     }
                  ]
               }
            }
         ],
         "reference":"Organization/132336"
      },
      {
         "extension":[
            {
               "url":"http://catsalut.gencat.cat/fhir/StructureDefinition/patient-tipus-relacio",
               "valueCodeableConcept":{
                  "coding":[
                     {
                        "system":"http://catsalut.gencat.cat/fhir/StructureDefinition/tipus-rel-organitzacio",
                        "code":"UPAPTERRI"
                     }
                  ]
               }
            }
         ],
         "reference":"Organization/132346"
      }
   ]
}
{
   "generalPractitioner":[
      {
         "extension":[
            {
               "url":"http://catsalut.gencat.cat/fhir/StructureDefinition/patient-tipus-relacio",
               "valueCodeableConcept":{
                  "coding":[
                     {
                        "system":"http://catsalut.gencat.cat/fhir/StructureDefinition/tipus-rel-organitzacio",
                        "code":"UPAPASSIG"
                     }
                  ]
               }
            }
         ],
         "reference":"Organization/132336"
      }
   ]
}
```

I'm trying:

> `jq --raw-output '[ ( .generalPractitioner[0] | ( .extension[] | .url, ( .valueCodeableConcept | .coding[] | .system, .code ) ), .reference ), ( .generalPractitioner[1] | ( .extension[] | .url, ( .valueCodeableConcept | .coding[] | .system, .code ) ), .reference ) ] | @csv`

Tyding up, filter expression is:

```
[
  ( .generalPractitioner[0] |
    ( .extension[] |
        .url,
        ( .valueCodeableConcept |
          .coding[] |
            .system,
            .code
        )
     ),
     .reference
  ),
    ( .generalPractitioner[1] |
    ( .extension[] |
        .url,
        ( .valueCodeableConcept |
          .coding[] |
            .system,
            .code
        )
     ),
     .reference
  ),
] | @csv
```

I'm getting this message:

> jq: error (at :55): Cannot iterate over null (null)

Second `generalPractitioner` object only contains 1 element.

I know I'm trying to get access to an element doesn't exist.

I don't quite figure out how to workaround it using a default `null` object.

What I'm trying to get is this:

```
.generalPractitioner[0].extension[0].url // null, .generalPractitioner[0].extension[0].valueCodeableConcept.coding[0].system // null, .generalPractitioner[0].extension[0].valueCodeableConcept.coding[0].code // null, .generalPractitioner[0].reference // null,
.generalPractitioner[1].extension[0].url // null, .generalPractitioner[0].extension[0].valueCodeableConcept.coding[0].system // null, .generalPractitioner[1].extension[0].valueCodeableConcept.coding[0].code // null, .generalPractitioner[1].reference // null,
.generalPractitioner[2].extension[0].url // null, .generalPractitioner[0].extension[0].valueCodeableConcept.coding[0].system // null, .generalPractitioner[2].extension[0].valueCodeableConcept.coding[0].code // null, .generalPractitioner[2].reference // null,
.generalPractitioner[3].extension[0].url // null, .generalPractitioner[0].extension[0].valueCodeableConcept.coding[0].system // null, .generalPractitioner[3].extension[0].valueCodeableConcept.coding[0].code // null, .generalPractitioner[3].reference // null
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Check the [manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) for the "Error Suppression / Optional Operator" `?` and the "Alternative operator" `//`. Depending on your final goal, using `.extension[]?` might already suffice.

Comment: I've tried adding `extension[]?` bit now I facing with this issue: csv line should have `content...,,,`, but I'm only getting `content,`. How could I force to add nulls (csv commas`,,`)?

Comment: The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70183565/2158479) to your previous question might solve exactly that.

Comment: I'm trying to adapt your approach. Could you give me some help. [jqplay I'm currently working](https://jqplay.org/s/tX-JBBbqVL). I'd really appreacite your help.

Comment: I've edited post with some additional explanation what I need to get. I've posted a very roughtly code... but it's what I need to get...

Comment: Your desired output is unclear to me. Is the edited block one line of CSV output? If no, why are they ending with a comma? If yes, it contains many duplicates (`.generalPractitioner[0].extension[0].valueCodeableConcept.coding[0].system` appears four times). It'd be much easier if you gave the **actual and complete** output that you expect from [this](https://jqplay.org/s/tX-JBBbqVL) input.

Comment: Sorry, I mistyping. [Here](https://jqplay.org/s/B6oYrKkxcj) you can find desired output from input.

Comment: So, for your 16 columns you want the second, sixth, tenth and fourteenth always to be the same string value, even if the *other* values are missing, right? (That's what confused me all along. As every modulo 4+1 column has that one value even if surrounded by `null` values (the second row in your output ends in `,,"<string>",,`), it's not the *simply rigged* case anymore...)

Answer (score 0):

As you want to generate the columns by iterating over an array (`.generalPractitioner[]`) while interweaving the output with a constant from a specific iteration step (`.generalPractitioner[0]`) in every fourth column starting with the second, you will have to store that value in a variable (`$system`) to access it from within the iteration.

```sh
jq -r '
  [
    .generalPractitioner
    | .[0].extension[0].valueCodeableConcept.coding[0].system as $system
    | .[range(4)]
    | (.extension[0] | .url, $system, .valueCodeableConcept.coding[0].code),
      .reference
  ]
  | @csv
'
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/a4zl5NnBVE)